# How to create jquery Tabs in native android

Tags: java, android, view, tabs

I wanted to know how to create the same ui as in the jquery tabs of following link:

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

I am concerned with the look and feel the view underneath the selected tabs should be looking exactly the way it is shown in the link above.

Also I need to change the background image of the tab i have 2 separate image for selected and unselected tabs.

How to go ahead with this please guide me with example or tutorial?

I searched a lot but was unable to find any technique for doing this attaching the image for reference

[image: The ui of the tab view should look exactly like given in the image]

Thanks in Advance please do reply.

Comment: Can anyone help me out with the above issue please somebody reply. :(